# Access data on an array multidimesion that converted to JSON using jquery on change

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, codeigniter

I have an array on php that I loaded to html. In CI3, this is the interpretation.
**CONTROLLER**

```
public function menu_container() {
    $this->load->library('csvreader');
    $data = array('pages' => 'Data Container',
        'csvData' => $this->csvreader->parse_file(base_url('assets/csv/ZIL.csv')),        
    $main_view = $this->load->view('surveyor/v_container', $data, TRUE);
    echo $main_view;
}
```

See, I have csvData in my Array. The content of CSVData looked like this:

```
Array
(
[1] => Array
    (
        [ NO] =>     1
        [EIR IN] => 1545053   
        [CONT] => EOLU 1111111
        [TYPE] => XXXX
        [INDEPO] => 21-11-2015
        [JAM] => 13:00
        [KODE VSL] => ABO
        [VESSEL] => ALBERT OLDENDORFF   
        [VOY] => N001   
        [CONSIG] => ASTABUMI CIPTA      
        [COND IN] => DMG
        [CLEAN] => DIRTY
        [TARE] =>   2400
        [GROSS] =>  20000
        [KAPASITAS] =>   5000
        [EX CARGO] => FOOD                
        [LAST AIR)] =>   -  -    
        [LAST HIDRO] =>   -  -    
        [MANU] => 10-11  
        [BUILDER] =>                     
        [OWNER] => APL                 
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [ NO] =>     2
        [EIR IN] => 1545052   
        [CONT] => EOLU 1234567
        [TYPE] => IM04
        [INDEPO] => 21-11-2015
        [JAM] => 10:00
        [KODE VSL] => 202
        [VESSEL] => WAN HAI 202         
        [VOY] => N 001  
        [CONSIG] => ANUGERAH AGUNG LUMIN
        [COND IN] => AVL
        [CLEAN] => DIRTY
        [TARE] =>   2400
        [GROSS] =>  20000
        [KAPASITAS] =>   1000
        [EX CARGO] => MAKANAN             
        [LAST AIR)] =>   -  -    
        [LAST HIDRO] =>   -  -    
        [MANU] => 11-13  
        [BUILDER] =>                     
        [OWNER] => APL                 
    )
```

)

I interprated those array in **VIEW** like this :

```
<select data-plac class="form-control input-lg pull-right chosen" style="width: 250px;" id="search" >
   <?php
       foreach ($csvData as $v) {
          echo '<option value ='. $v['EIR IN'].'>' . $v['EIR IN'] . '- ' . $v['CONT'] . '</option>';
       }
    ?>
</select>
```

The storyboard is like this. Just say,the user choose first option, the EIR-IN is `15403`, the all information in first array like NO, CONT, and so on will be display on another html.

```
<tr>
  <td>EIR / Estimate Reference</td>
  <td id="EIR_IN"></td> //The value that  came from selected option
  <td>CONT</td>
  <td id="CONT"></td> //The value
```

Now, I decided to using jquery to manage those data. I use on change event.

```
var jsoncsv = '<?php echo json_encode($csvData); ?>';
$(document).on("change", '#search', function(){
   var selected = $('#search').val() ;
   //ACCESS THE JSON
});
```

What should I do ? Any solution is so appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle the json inside jQuery you can try something like

```
var jsoncsv = '<?php echo json_encode($csvData); ?>';
$(document).on("change", '#search', function(){
   var selected = $('#search').val() ;
   var obj = JSON.parse(jsoncsv);
   console.log(obj);
   //running a each loop:
   $.each(obj, function(key,value) {
      console.log(key + value);
   });
});
```

Good luck!